# Using ijson to read json data from a specific key

Tags: python, pandas, json-normalize

I have several large json files I'm trying to load into a pandas dataframe. I've discovered a typical way to work with large jsons in Python is with the ijson module. The jsons I have represent geo located tweet id's. I'm only interested in tweet id's that come from the US. The json data looks like this:

```
{
  "tweet_id": "1223655173056356353",
  "created_at": "Sat Feb 01 17:11:42 +0000 2020",
  "user_id": "3352471150",
  "geo_source": "user_location",
  "user_location": {
    "country_code": "br"
  },
  "geo": {},
  "place": {
    
  },
  "tweet_locations": [
    {
      "country_code": "it",
      "state": "Trentino-Alto",
      "county": "Pustertal - Val Pusteria"
    },
    {
      "country_code": "us"
    },
    {
      "country_code": "ru",
      "state": "Voronezh Oblast",
      "county": "Petropavlovsky District"
    },
    {
      "country_code": "at",
      "state": "Upper Austria",
      "county": "Braunau am Inn"
    },
    {
      "country_code": "it",
      "state": "Trentino-Alto",
      "county": "Pustertal - Val Pusteria"
    },
    {
      "country_code": "cn"
    },
    {
      "country_code": "in",
      "state": "Himachal Pradesh",
      "county": "Jubbal"
    }
  ]
}
```

How would I use ijson to select tweet IDs from the US only, and subsequently put these US IDs into a dataframe? The ijson module is new to me, and I do not understand how to approach this task. More specifically, I want to get all tweet IDs such that the country code in `user_location` is US, or the country code in `tweet_locations` is US. All help is appreciated!

Comment: My apologies! I missed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

- *Normalize semi-structured JSON data into a flat table.*
- `data` is your JSON dict
- [Pandas: Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

  - [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)
- Data: [Tweets with geo info (English)](https://crisisnlp.qcri.org/covid19) (pick 1)

  - Each file contains rows of dictionaries.
  - They are not inside a list or tuple, so each row is read.
  - The value for `tweet_locations`, is a list of dicts
  - The value for `user_location`, is a dict
- For the case where `tweet_locations` is an empty list, `[]` instead of `[{}]`, the row is not included in the dataframe because of the way `json_normalize` expects to see the `metadata` fields.

  - The `tweet_id` from `{"tweet_id":"1256223765513584641","created_at":"Fri May 01 14:07:39 +0000 2020","user_id":"772487185031311360","geo_source":"user_location","user_location":{"country_code":"us"},"geo":{},"place":{},"tweet_locations":[]}` will **not** be included in the data.

    - This can be fixed by setting `"tweet_locations" = [{}]` when `"tweet_locations":[]` is `True`

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
from pathlib import Path

# path to file, which contains the sample data at the bottom of this answer
file = Path('data/test.json')  # some path to your file

# load file
data = list()
with file.open('r') as f:
    for line in f:  # the file is rows of dicts that must be read 1 at a time
        data.append(json.loads(line))

# create dataframe
df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'tweet_locations', ['tweet_id', ['user_location', 'country_code']], errors='ignore')

# display(df.head())
  country_code              state         county    city             tweet_id user_location.country_code
0           us           Illinois  McLean County  Normal  1256223753220034566                        NaN
1           ke      Kiambu County            NaN     NaN  1256223748904161280                         ca
2           us           Illinois  McLean County  Normal  1256223744122593287                         us
3           th  Saraburi Province            NaN     NaN  1256223753463365632                        NaN
4           in              Assam          Lanka     NaN  1256223753463365632                        NaN                       br

# filter for US in the two columns
us = df[(df.country_code == 'us') | (df['user_location.country_code'] == 'us')]

# display(us)
   country_code          state          county    city             tweet_id user_location.country_code
0            us       Illinois   McLean County  Normal  1256223753220034566                        NaN
2            us       Illinois   McLean County  Normal  1256223744122593287                         us
15           us       Michigan  Sanilac County     NaN  1256338355106672640                         in
16           us  West Virginia     Clay County     NaN  1256338355106672640                         in
18           us        Florida   Taylor County     NaN  1256338355106672640                         in

# get unique tweet_id
df_tweet_ids = df.tweet_id.unique().tolist()

print(df_tweet_ids)
['1256223753220034566', '1256223744122593287', '1256338355106672640']
```

### To load and parse all JSON files

- Never more than one file will be fully loaded at a time
- Use [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to combine the list of dataframes, `us_data`

```py
# path to files
p = Path('c:/path_to_files')

# get of all json files
files = list(p.rglob('*.json'))

# parse files
us_data = list()
for file in files:
    data = list()
    with file.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            data.append(json.loads(line))

        # create dataframe
        df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'tweet_locations', ['tweet_id', ['user_location', 'country_code']], errors='ignore')

        # filter for US in the two columns
        df = df[(df.country_code == 'us') | (df['user_location.country_code'] == 'us')]
        
        us_data.append(df)


# combine all data into one dataframe
us = pd.concat(us_data)

# delete objects that are no longer needed
del(data)
del(df)
del(us_data)
```

## Parse only the `tweet_id` without pandas

- Because the files are rows of dicts, `ijson` is not needed.
- As written, this will include the `tweet_id` if `country_code` is `'us'`, even if `tweet_locations` is an empty list.

  - The `tweet_id` from `{"tweet_id":"1256223765513584641","created_at":"Fri May 01 14:07:39 +0000 2020","user_id":"772487185031311360","geo_source":"user_location","user_location":{"country_code":"us"},"geo":{},"place":{},"tweet_locations":[]}` will be included in the data.

```py
file = Path('data/en_geo_2020-05-01/en_geo_2020-05-01.json')
tweet_ids = list()
with file.open('r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = json.loads(line)
        if line.get('user_location').get('country_code') == 'us':
            tweet_ids.append(line.get('tweet_id'))
        else:
            if line['tweet_locations']:  # if tweet_locations is a list and not empty (None)
                tweet_locations_country_code = [i.get('country_code') for i in line['tweet_locations']]  # get the coutry_code for each tweet
                if 'us' in tweet_locations_country_code:  # if 'us' is in the list
                    tweet_ids.append(line.get('tweet_id'))  # append

print(tweet_ids)
['1256223753220034566', '1256223744122593287', '1256338355106672640']
```

### Sample data

- The data is rows of dictionaries in a file

```py
{"tweet_id":"1256223753220034566","created_at":"Fri May 01 14:07:36 +0000 2020","user_id":"916540973190078465","geo_source":"tweet_text","user_location":{},"geo":{},"place":{},"tweet_locations":[{"country_code":"us","state":"Illinois","county":"McLean County","city":"Normal"}]}
{"tweet_id":"1256223748904161280","created_at":"Fri May 01 14:07:35 +0000 2020","user_id":"697426379583983616","geo_source":"user_location","user_location":{"country_code":"ca"},"geo":{},"place":{},"tweet_locations":[{"country_code":"ke","state":"Kiambu County"}]}
{"tweet_id":"1256223744122593287","created_at":"Fri May 01 14:07:34 +0000 2020","user_id":"1277481013","geo_source":"user_location","user_location":{"country_code":"us","state":"Florida"},"geo":{},"place":{},"tweet_locations":[{"country_code":"us","state":"Illinois","county":"McLean County","city":"Normal"}]}
{"tweet_id":"1256223753463365632","created_at":"Fri May 01 14:07:36 +0000 2020","user_id":"596005899","geo_source":"tweet_text","user_location":{},"geo":{},"place":{},"tweet_locations":[{"country_code":"th","state":"Saraburi Province"},{"country_code":"in","state":"Assam","county":"Lanka"},{"country_code":"cz","state":"Northeast","county":"okres \u00dast\u00ed nad Orlic\u00ed"},{"country_code":"lk"}]}
{"tweet_id":"1256223753115238406","created_at":"Fri May 01 14:07:36 +0000 2020","user_id":"139159502","geo_source":"user_location","user_location":{"country_code":"ca"},"geo":{},"place":{},"tweet_locations":[{"country_code":"ve"},{"country_code":"ca","state":"Nova Scotia","county":"Pictou County","city":"Diamond"},{"country_code":"my","state":"Selangor","city":"Kajang"}]}
{"tweet_id":"1256223748161757190","created_at":"Fri May 01 14:07:35 +0000 2020","user_id":"1655021437","geo_source":"user_location","user_location":{"country_code":"af","state":"Nangarhar","county":"Kot"},"geo":{},"place":{},"tweet_locations":[{"country_code":"cz","state":"Northeast","county":"okres \u00dast\u00ed nad Orlic\u00ed"},{"country_code":"cz","state":"Northeast","county":"okres \u00dast\u00ed nad Orlic\u00ed"},{"country_code":"gb","state":"England","county":"Gloucestershire"}]}
{"tweet_id":"1256223749214437380","created_at":"Fri May 01 14:07:35 +0000 2020","user_id":"3244990814","geo_source":"user_location","user_location":{"country_code":"se"},"geo":{},"place":{},"tweet_locations":[{"country_code":"cg","state":"Kouilou","county":"Pointe-Noire"},{"country_code":"cn"}]}
{"tweet_id":"1256338355106672640","created_at":"Fri May 01 21:43:00 +0000 2020","user_id":"1205700416123486208","geo_source":"user_location","user_location":{"country_code":"in","state":"Delhi"},"geo":{},"place":{},"tweet_locations":[{"country_code":"us","state":"Michigan","county":"Sanilac County"},{"country_code":"us","state":"West Virginia","county":"Clay County"},{"country_code":"de","state":"Baden-W\u00fcrttemberg","county":"Verwaltungsgemeinschaft Friedrichshafen"},{"country_code":"us","state":"Florida","county":"Taylor County"}]}
{"tweet_id":"1256223764980944904","created_at":"Fri May 01 14:07:39 +0000 2020","user_id":"1124447266205503488","geo_source":"none","user_location":{},"geo":{},"place":{},"tweet_locations":[]}
{"tweet_id":"1256223760765595650","created_at":"Fri May 01 14:07:38 +0000 2020","user_id":"909477905737990144","geo_source":"tweet_text","user_location":{},"geo":{},"place":{},"tweet_locations":[{"country_code":"lr","state":"Grand Bassa County","county":"District # 2"}]}
```